# MySQL Insert Exception [JAVA]

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, exception, insert

I always get an exception when I try to insert with this code:

```
 String add="insert into kategorie kategorie values ?";
 PreparedStatement addKategorie=db.prepareStatement(add);
 addKategorie.setString(1,kategorie);
```

Whats wrong with my insert Syntax?

(Insert into table called kategorie and column called kategorie with prepared statement (Value=?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the exception message?

Comment: Did you even try to look up the correct syntax in the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be something like below:

```
insert into kategorie(kategorie) values (?)
```

Comment: Yeah I looked it up, but I realised there were two different Exceptions (One was because of the syntax -> which is fixed, and the other one was because I didnt auto increase the PK ID - So shame on me) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`insert into  kategorie (kategorie) values ?`

As proper syntax for inserting is

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```